# How do I slog to OutOrStdout() and OutOrStderr()?

Tags: go, go-cobra

Using Cobra I want all output to be in my structured logging format.

The problem is in order to use `SetOut()` and `SetErr()` in my tests I need to send output like this:

`fmt.Fprint(cmd.OutOrStderr(), "my output")`
`fmt.Fprint(cmd.OutOrStdout(), "my output")`

This is how I'm doing this now and it works, but I want to know if there is a simpler way:

```
// Use buffers to capture log output to manually send it through cmd methods
var (
    stdout         = bytes.NewBufferString("")
    stderr         = bytes.NewBufferString("")
    lout = slog.New(slog.NewJSONHandler(bout, nil))
    lerr = slog.New(slog.NewJSONHandler(berr, nil))
)

.......

// Log to the buffers and then redirect through cmd
lout.Info("my stdout output")
sout, _ := io.ReadAll(stdout)
fmt.Fprint(cmd.OutOrStdout(), string(sout))

lerr.Info("my stderr output")
lerr, _ := io.ReadAll(stderr)
fmt.Fprint(cmd.OutOrStderr(), string(lerr))
```

Now in my tests I can properly capture output like this:

```
b := bytes.NewBufferString("")
cmd.SetOut(b)
cmd.SetErr(b)
```

This works, but it feels like I'm doing more work then I need to do.

All I want is for my cobra output to be in my slogger format and be able to use `SetOut()` and `SetErr()` in my tests to redirect output as needed.